# How do I clear the "foreign configuration" status on a LSI RAID controller using storcli on windows?

Tags: windows, raid, lsi

I have a windows server with an LSI controller, and storcli installed.  We just added 4 spare drives to the server, and the controller is detecting two of the drives as "foreign".  How do I clear this "foreign" status from those two drives using storcli?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete the foreign configurations on a drive use the following:

```
storcli /cx/fx|fall del|delete
```

If you don't know the controller ID, you can run "storcli show" to see what controllers are detected (it is usually 0).  Using "storcli /c0 /fall show" will show you the foreign configurations found (change /c0 to whatever your controller ID is).

For example, if you have a foreign configuration on controller 0 with ID 3, you could clear it with:

```
storcli /c0/f3 delete
```

The above was tested in Linux, but the documentation looks to be the same for both operating systems.  The official documentation (PDF) can be found at [this link](http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/12352476).