# How check if UBad disk on LSI RAID is really failed

Tags: raid, lsi

I have taken over responsibility for a new server with an LSI RAID card, configured with 4 drives (in R10) plus one spare.  I normally manage RAID arrays by taking down the server and configuring via the LSI GUI (rom).

However, I cannot take this server down at the moment, so I installed the LSI CIM (on ESXi 6.7).  The storcli command shows the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                  Sp Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     3 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:1     5 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:2     6 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:3     7 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:4     4 UBad   F 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-0       U  -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see disk in slot 4 is marked as "UBad".  However, does this really mean it is failed?  It shows as spinning (Sp:U).  DG (Drive Group) shows as "F" - no idea what that means.  Could it be the drive was simply not configured as a hot spare?

Anything more I can do from the command line to see what is going on?  Is there any way to manage this from a GUI (in Linux, or second choice windows) which connects to the host computer via IP?

**UPDATE:**

I used the 'set good' parameter on the drive as suggested below, and also '/fall delete' and it no longer shows as a foreign config:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                  Sp Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     3 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:1     5 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:2     6 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:3     7 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:4     4 UGood  - 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice the full model number appears now...strange.  Is this a sign something is flaky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F` probably stands for "foreign" - was the disk used in another server?

The fact that the disk model is not correctly reported (WD6002FRYZ-0??????) is suspicious, but without taking SMART attributes into account it is difficult to tell if the disk is really broken or not.

You should be able to set it to `UGood` with the `set good` command, clear the foreign config with `delete` and re-add it to the array. If the disk really was ever attached to this server only, rather than `delete` you may try with `import` (in this case, better to first use `import preview`).

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/802890/how-do-i-clear-the-foreign-configuration-status-on-a-lsi-raid-controller-using) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/877314/how-to-add-a-hotspare-with-storcli-to-a-lsi-megaraid-controller) you can find similar references, but as you are working on a production system, be sure to understand what these commands will do on your system *before* issuing any of them. *Any error can led to data loss,* so stop here if your don't have a recent working backup.

Comment: Could you also comment on whether you think the suddenly appearing full model info is a sign of something flaky / something to worry about?  I'm concerned that I just forced a defective drive into production...not sure how I can settle this feeling.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without checking the disk SMART data. ESXi 5.x added support single-disk SMART attributes, but you are using an array and so you probably need `smartctl`, which is not included in ESXi (some 3rd party packages exists, but they are not produced by VMWare and so use them at your risk). Also, if the disk is shown as `UGood` (as per your update) you did not include it in the array yet.

Comment: I switched the drive to ugood and it ran fine, but 3 days later went back to ubad.  So I'm concluding it's failed.  As noted above no smart tools in ESXi 6 so I'll just pull it.